# Regular expression returns empty array in php even though the regular expression is correct

Tags: php, regex

This is my regular expression:

```
$pattern_new="/<td>(\n|\s)*?(<span(\n|\s|.)*?<\/strong>(\n|\s)*?\$(?<price>([0-9.]*)).*?)\$(.*?)(\n|\s)*?</";
```

This is the sample pattern from which I have to do a match:

```
<td><strong>.zx</strong></td><td><span class="offer"><strong>xscre:<br></strong>$299 xxxxx&x;xx<span class="fineprint_number">2</span></span><br>de&ea;s $399</td><td>zxcddcdcdcdc</td></tr><tr class="dark"><td><strong>.aa.rr</strong></td><td><span class="offer"><strong>xscre:<br></strong>$99 xxxxx&x;xx<span class="fineprint_number">2</span></span><br>de&eae;s $199</td><td>xxxx</td></tr><tr class="bar"><td colspan="3"></td></tr><tr class="bright"><td><strong>.vfd</strong></td><td><span class="offer"><strong>xscre:<br></strong>$99 xxxxx&x;xx<span class="fineprint_number">2</span></span><br>du&ee;s $199</td><td>xxxxxxxx</td></tr><tr class="dark"><td><strong>.qwe</strong></td><td><span class="offer"><strong>xxx<br></strong>$99 xxxc;o<span class="fineprint_number">2</span>
```

Here is what I am doing in PHP

```
$pattern_new="/<td>(\n|\s)*?(<span(\n|\s|.)*?<\/strong>(\n|\s)*?\$(<price>)*([0-9.]*).*?)\$(.*?)(\n|\s)*?</";
$source = file_get_contents("https://www.abc.com/sources/data.txt");
preg_match_all($pattern_new, $source, $match_newprice, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
echo$source;
print_r($match_newprice);
```

the`$match_newprice` is returning an empty array.

When I am using a regex tester like [myregextester](http://www.myregextester.com) or [solmetra.com](http://solmetra.com/scripts/regex/) I am getting a perfect match no issues at all but when I am using php `preg_match_all` to do the match it is returning an empty array. I increased the pcre.backtrack_limit but its still the same issue.
I don't seem to understand the problem. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I assume you were trying to do a noncapture group for `<price...` but you missed the `:`... `(?:<price..`

Comment: No that does solve the issue because I am mining another pattern '$pattern_do="/<strong>(?<do>\.(<\w*>)?(.*?)(<\/\w*>)?)<\/strong>/";' works perfectly. Update: the above pattern works fine when I use perl but my requirement is in PHP

Comment: What is this `<span(\n|\s|.)*?<\/strong>`? Maybe you meant `<span[\\s]+.*?<\/strong>`. Why use `()` instead of `[]`. I think you need DOMDocument and DOMXPath to help you as you're kind of breaking your neck with this convoluted and quite bad regexp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another problem which is PHP related with this:

```
<?php
echo "\$".PHP_EOL;
echo '\$'.PHP_EOL;
```

Result:

```
$
\$
```

... as in double quoted strings the `$` is expected to signify the start of a variable, and needs escaping if you mean a bare `$`. Put single quotes around your regex & it will probably be fine (haven't looked at in detail though, you may want to use the `/x` option & add some formatting whitespace/comments if you need to debug this a half year from now).

Comment: Perfect,thank you very much I was raking my brain since yesterday to solve this issue. Putting Single quotes worked like a charm. I think now I understand the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you were trying to do a noncapture group for `<price...` but you missed the `:`. Or you should take out the question mark. If the `price` group is optional, try like the regex below. You should use the following website to help you with regex. I find it extremely helpful.

```
<td>(\n|\s)*?(<span(\n|\s|.)*?<\/strong>(\n|\s)*?\$(<price>)*([0-9.]*).*?)\$(.*?)(\n|\s)*?<
```

[image: Regular expression image]

[Edit live on Debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/r/uHiil2W0LH0G5V-H)

In the above example, your first match would have the following captures:

```
0: "<td><span class="offer"><strong>xscre:<br></strong>$299 xxxxx&x;xx<span class="fineprint_number">2</span></span><br>de&ea;s $399<"
1: ""
2: "<span class="offer"><strong>xscre:<br></strong>$299 xxxxx&x;xx<span class="fineprint_number">2</span></span><br>de&ea;s "
3: ">"
4: ""
5: ""
6: "299"
7: "399"
8: ""
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: I put the price there so that when I do a preg_match_all I get in the array with a name like this:'preg_match_all($pattern_new, $source, $match_newprice, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);' and the output is in 'match_newprice(
    [0] => Array() price=>array())' in this way I can automate the process and dont have to look back

Comment: so is the price bit optional? I'll update the post with what I think you are looking for now. also, perhaps it would help if you show what text you are hoping will match exactly.

Comment: I am trying to capture the 299, 99, 99, 99 values

Comment: The most recent update reaches the numbers (and puts them in a capture group) as you can see if you click "Edit live on Debuggex". Is this what you are going for?

Comment: Yes that is what I was going for but the issue here is I am not able capture the numbers when I use php preg_match_all I am not able to capture the numbers. It works when I am using PERL.

Comment: The regex you modified is working and my initial regex is working when I use PERL but when I use PHP it returns an empty array

Answer (score 1):

The good way to do that:

```
$oProductsHTML = new DOMDocument();
@$oProductsHTML->loadHTML($sHtml);

$oSpanNodes = $oProductsHTML->getElementsByTagName('span');

foreach ($oSpanNodes as $oSpanNode) {
    if (preg_match('~\boffer\b~', $oSpanNode->getAttribute('class')) &&
        preg_match('~\$\K\d++~', $oSpanNode->nodeValue, $aMatch) )
    {
        $sPrice = $aMatch[0];
        echo '<br/>' . $sPrice;
    }
}
```

`$sHtml` stands for your string.

And i'm sure you can make it shorter with XPath.

The bad way:

```
$sPattern = '~<span class="offer\b(?>[^>]++|>(?!\$))+>\$\K\d++~';
preg_match_all($sPattern, $sHtml, $aMatches);

print_r ($aMatches[0]);
```

Notice: `\d++` can be replaced by `\d++(?>\.\d++)?` to allow decimal numbers.

Comment: This solution also works. Thanks. I will use it the next time.